# Finding the index of the lowest non-zero value in a list

Tags: r, list, indexing

I have a list as follows:

```
alist <- list(0.147293560981687, 0.124073985832788, 0.071172828740332, 
    0.0650147970461593, 0.0706446776127474, 0.0851406172884224, 
    0.0915347157882129, 0.0964307208897466, 0.115968630433955, 
    0.12558846846113, 0)
```

I would like to extract the index of the lowest number non-zero number in the list, which if I am not mistaken is 4.

Because of the zero, I cannot do:

```
min( unlist(alist ))
```

How should I do this?

## EDIT:

Showing the issue with the proposed answer of bpvalderrama, which works because the position of the `0` above does not influence the indexes in the subset. However if the (for example) the first value is `0`, it no longer works, because the indexes of the subset are no longer identical to the original list.

```
alist <- list(0, 0.124073985832788, 0.071172828740332, 
    0.0650147970461593, 0.0706446776127474, 0.0851406172884224, 
    0.0915347157882129, 0.0964307208897466, 0.115968630433955, 
    0.12558846846113, 0)

which.min(alist[alist>0])

[1] 3
```

Comment: just as a comment: It seems that the function you are looking for is `which.min` instead of `min`. The later gives the actual value, while the former gives you the index of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try with :

```
which.min(alist[alist>0])
```

which will give you the following **output** :

```
[1] 4
```

---

### **EDIT :**

Since Tom wanted to keep the 0 values in the vector (which I didn't notice), you can use :

```
alist <- list(0, 0.124073985832788, 0.071172828740332, 
              0.0650147970461593, 0.0706446776127474, 0.0851406172884224, 
              0.0915347157882129, 0.0964307208897466, 0.115968630433955, 
              0.12558846846113, 0)


which.min(replace(alist, alist<=0, NA))
```

And the 0 are still kept as position holders but not considered in the `which.min()` call since now they are `NA`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this only works because the zero is in the last position. If I make the first entry zero as well it does not give the right index anymore (I did not mean to downvote, I just wanted to take my upvote back after I realised).

Comment: I ran this : `alist <- list(0, 0.147293560981687, 0.124073985832788, 0.071172828740332, 
              0.0650147970461593, 0.0706446776127474, 0.0851406172884224, 
              0.0915347157882129, 0.0964307208897466, 0.115968630433955, 
              0.12558846846113, 0)

which.min(alist[alist>0])` and the output is still 4 even if there is another 0 and it is at the first possition

Comment: That is really weird! Let me see if I did something wrong then.

Comment: Of course, you can copy paste the code and see it by yourself

Comment: The problem is that you added a zero, instead of replacing the first value..

Comment: oohh, I see the issue. You never said that you wanted to keep the zero values. If that is the situation, you can use : `which.min(replace(alist, alist<=0, NA))`

Comment: Already done! I think you should mark as correct as well for future references ;)